# How to read a data file containing survey form options into models.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am creating a survey form which will have rather a lot of drop downs with user choices. This is making my models.py quite cluttered.

How would I go about storing the options in a separate data file so that they can be read by each of the models?

The sample below is designed to allow the user to pick which state they live in. I have not included all the states for brevity.

Thanks for the help, I'm new to Django, and coding in general and learning as i go.

```
class StateChoice(forms.Form):

    ALABAMA = 'Alabama'
    ALASKA = 'Alaska'
    #...

    #...
    WISCONSIN = 'Wisconsin'
    WYOMING = 'Wyoming'

    STATE = (
        (ALABAMA, 'Alabama'),
        (ALASKA, 'Alaska'),
        #...

        #...
        (WISCONSIN, 'Wisconsin'),
        (WYOMING, 'Wyoming'),

            )

    state = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=STATE, initial=ALABAMA)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.STATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `django-localflavor` library to help out a bit: http://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/localflavor/us/

```
from django.db import models
from localflavor.us.us_states import US_STATES
class StateChoice(models.Model):
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=US_STATES)
```

Or, create simply move all those constants you have to another file, e.g. `utils.py` in your app's directory.

So utils.py has:

```
ALABAMA = 'Alabama'
...

STATES = ((ALABAMA, ALABAMA), ...)
```

and your model looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from .utils import STATES
class StateChoice(models.Model):
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATES)
```